# Paraview clip/slice filter "show plane" in python

Tags: paraview, pvpython

I am trying to untick "show plane" using python but I didn't find any working solution. Is there some command for it?

Found this: https://public.kitware.com/pipermail/paraview/2011-July/022283.html, but trace option doesn't track ticking the "show plane" box for neither option of tracing.

Also found this: https://www.paraview.org/pipermail/paraview-developers/2013-November/002667.html but I'm not sure what to make of it.

[side bar for clip settings in paraview picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PdaHb.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hide3DWidgets(proxy=clip1) does the trick. See the python doc here : https://kitware.github.io/paraview-docs/latest/python/paraview.simple.html#paraview.simple.Hide3DWidgets